GoogleGenerativeAIError: ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT
I'm encountering an error while attempting to make a POST request to the Google Generative Language API. I’m working on a project that requires embedding text using the embedding-001 model. Below are the details:
Screenshot of the all the roles provided and enabled for service account:
Screenshot of Service account roles
Issue: I'm trying to embed text using the Google Generative AI API, but I keep receiving the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.ai.generativelanguage.v1beta.GenerativeService.BatchEmbedContents",
          "service": "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


What I've tried so far:



I’ve generated a service account key and added the necessary scopes for Generative Language API:
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language"]
​




I’ve used the following authentication method:



credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    service_account_key_path, scopes=scopes
)
credentials.refresh(Request())

​

The access token seems to be generated correctly, but the API call fails with insufficient scope permissions.

Error Response: Despite following the official documentation, I continue to receive the ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT error. I’ve verified the service account and scopes multiple times.

Questions:

Am I missing any specific permissions or scopes for the Generative AI API?
Is there any additional configuration required for embedding text using the embedding-001 model?


Where is that scope documented? It's not shown on Google OAuth Scopes. Not that it solves this problem but it's better to use Application Default Credentials and then use gcloud.auth.default(scopes=[...])

Can you also show the code for your request?
